# How add Oracle managedaataaccess dll to Script Task in ssis

Tags: c#, oracle, ssis

I need to make a connection to oracle via in ssis package. It occurred to me to implement the connection in a console application in c#

1. First install the Oracle Managed Data Access nuget package in the console application

> Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core -Version 2.19.70

2. Then I made the connection and the result was correct
3. Copy the folder that downloaded the nuget installation to a path in C:, In the SSIS 2017 script task add the dll as a reference, but when executing the package it shows me the following error:
   **Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation** And does not show more detail.

location where you deposit the nuget package [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mC4K.png)

I add the assembly from reference s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaePK.png)

Interruption point, which does not enter [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJCgB.png)

4. put a breakpoint in the script task, but don't start. I'm thinking it's because of the dll

any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either install the components in the GAC (I believe there's an installer for that component that does), or register an [AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac) event to find the assembly in a custom location.  EG

Comment: I had come across something similar on the web. GAC registration only? the following line would help me to register whith next comand **gacutil /i c:\oracle\oracle..Folder\lib\net40\Oraclle.ManagedDataAccess.dll**